# Don't pass controller for method instantiating services

Tags: php

In a class (name it a) I have a method, that instantiates multiple objects of the same class (name it b) (based on some conditions, that are irrelevant). Both classes are registered as services in my container.
Currently I am passing my controller to the method to make it able to request instances of the class b, like so:

```
class a {

    public method createBs(ContainerInterface $container) {
        foreach ($x as $y) {
            $b = $container->get('b');
            //do some shit with b
        }
    }
}
```

But it bugs me to pass the container, because I think it is bad code design. Has anyone an idea how i can get rid of the passed container?

Comment: Why are you referring to a service locator antipattern as "container"? Also, this is not dependency injection.

Comment: @tereško yes it is. You can devine dependencies as many as u want, but at some point you will need to ask the container for a "root" instance. That's why a container has the get() method. [link](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-11/)

Comment: No it is not. What you have there is a **service locator**. Is is not a dependency injection container.  Please learn the difference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could pass a factory to it instead, where the factory handles creating objects of class `b`:

```
class BFactory
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct($container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return $container->get('b');
    }
}
```

That way, the method within `a` will only ever be able to create objects of `b`. However, you'd just end up sending the container to the factory so it can create objects of `b`, so it's really a matter of who you want to have the container exposed to.

Another option is to apply the same factory pattern, but instead specify it  with a lambda, something like:

```
$container; // Predefined
$lambda = function() use (&$container) {
    return $container->get('b');
}
$a = new a();
$a->createBs($lambda);
```

Then in `a`, you'd do:

```
public function createBs($factory) {
    $b = $factory();
}
```

Comment: Please add a comment if you DV.

Comment: Factory pattern in not a wrapper for service locator and you do not understand what happens, when you pass an object by reference.